# C# Pong Game - problem with ball scripting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I was just copying a tutorial on YouTube on how to make the pong game and when it came to scripting the ball, there was an error for me but not the guy in the video.

I have no experience in C#, only Python. This is the error message:

> Assets\Ball.cs(24,26): error CS0117: 'Random' does not contain a definition for 'range'

Anyone know what's wrong?

This is the script for it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    //Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Launch();
    }
    //Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void Launch()

    {
        float x = Random.range(0,2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        float y = Random.range(0,2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * x, speed * y);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's Random.Range(), it's case sensitive

Comment: And in that case, i think you probably want to use float instead of int in the Range method  (Random.Range(0f, 2f)). If I remember correctly, in unity's Random.Range() method, if you give two int, the method will return an int (not 100% sure tho)

Comment: Well, just realised that the Random isn't stored, don't mind the float thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Random.Range and not Random.range

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize "range",  Random.Range is a method and most methods start with a capital letter so instead of "Random.range", you need to type "Random.Range"

Answer (score 0):

Here the script method just calls the "Launch()" method at initialization time, your "Lauch()" method is problematic, you can try to modify the "Random.range(0,2)" method to "Random.Range(0, 2)"